# Twitter Bootstrap: Why do hidden elements affect layout?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I have a three-column fluid layout using Twitter Bootstrap's fluid grid layout system. The three columns are made up of `span4` divs. I am also using a jQuery UI script that swaps one element for another within that grid system meaning that, for brief periods of time, I actually have a hidden fourth element in my row. I would have thought that this wouldn't be a problem because the hidden elements are, well, hidden ("display:none").

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dhilowitz/cfZwv/6/

**My question is this**:

Why are the elements in the row not displaying as a row? If I take that hidden element out, everything works beautifully. Put it back in and my row breaks and displays as two rows.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="hide"><h2>Item 1A</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p></div>
        <div class="span4 element"><h2>Item 1B</h2>This is a node that should be treated exactly like the other ones.</div>
        <!--/span-->
        <div class="span4 element"><h2>Item #2</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p></div>
        <!--/span-->
        <div class="span4 element"><h2>Item #3</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p></div>
        <!--/span-->
    </div>
    <!--/row-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of this rule in bootstrap:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

The hidden element is still the `:first-child`.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. It seems it's actually not so much that the first (hidden) element is the `:first-child` but that the second element (the first *visible* element) is *not* the `:first-child`. If I apply `margin-left: 0` to that second element everything works. Now, if I could only update/override that CSS selector to apply that style to the `:first-visible-child` I'd be golden.

Comment: you could try `.row-fluid [class*="span"].hide:first-child + [class*="span"]`, though that's a hell of a selector...

Comment: Here's the quick JavaScript fix: http://jsfiddle.net/dhilowitz/MvcdN/. Since these hidden elements are going to be created dynamically, I can add this class and then remove it as needed.